# Apostrophe issue

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I have built a search engine using php and mysql.

Problem:
When I submit a word with an apostrophe in it and return the value to the text field using $_GET the apostrophe has been replaced with a backslash and all characters after the apostrophe are missing.

Example: 
Submitted Words: `Just can't get enough`
Returned Value (Using $_GET): `Just can\`
Also the url comes up like this:`search=just+can%27t+get+enough`

As you can see the ' has been replaced with a \ and get enough is missing.

Question:
Does anybody know what causes this to happen and what is the solution to fix this problem?

The code: 
http://tinypaste.com/11d62

Comment: Is it correct in the table? If not, perhaps you did not escape it when you saved the data. Apos must be doubled, eg update ... set col1 = 'I don''t know' ...

Comment: Can you show examples of more of your code? This doesn't happen for me.

Comment: Try running urldecode on the get, and then mysql_real_escape_string (to make it safe for database use).  Don't know if that is the problem, but worth a shot.  Like MGwynne said, this shouldn't happen when you access the get variable, it might happen when you add it to the database though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of "value to the text field" I speculate you have some output code like this:

```
 Redisplay
 <input value='<?=$_GET['search']?>'>
```

In that case the contained single quote will terminate the html attribute. And anything behind the single quote is simply garbage to the browser. In this case applying [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to the output helps.

(The backslash is likely due to magic_quotes or mysql_*_escape before outputting the text. I doubt the question describes a database error here.)

---

**Update**: It seems it's indeed an output problem here:

```
  echo "<a href='searchmusic.php?search=$search&s=$next'>Next</a>";
```

Regardless of if you use single or double quotes you would need:

```
  echo "<a href='searchmusic.php?search="
      . htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($search))
      . "&s=$next'>Next</a>";
```

(Notice that using `stripslashes` is a workaround here. You should preserve the original search text, or [`disable the magic_quotes`](http://www.google.com/search?q=disable%20the%20magic_quotes) rather.)

---

Okay I forgot something crucial. [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) needs the **ENT_QUOTES** parameter - always, and in your case particularly:

```
// prepare for later output:
$search = $_GET['search'];
$html_search = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($search), ENT_QUOTES);
```

And then use that whereever you wanted to display $search before:

```
  echo "<a href='searchmusic.php?search=$html_search&s=$next'>Next</a>";
```

Comment: You need to apply `htmlspecialchars()` *everywhere* you tried to output `$search`. For simplicity I would advise you do a `$html_search = htmlspecialchars($search, ENT_QUOTES);` once, and then print `$html_search` instead.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've updated the answer. (That was too unreadable in a comment really.)

Comment: After i replaced $search = $_GET['search']; with $html_search = htmlspecialchars($search, ENT_QUOTES); it won't let me search anything. If i type something it says you must enter more then 3 characters.

Comment: No, you need both lines still. The `$search` is for the database queries. And the `$html_search` for the html output.

Comment: where do i put $html_search = htmlspecialchars($search, ENT_QUOTES);

Comment: See update again. Put it right below your original `$search = $_GET['search'];`

Comment: ok i get the apostrophe but now it shows up three backward slash for example if i click Next it shows : No results found for just can\\\'t get enough

Comment: Yeah, the backslashes will duplicate and triplicate the more page requests you have. This is due to the outdated `magic_quotes` setting on your server. Apply the `stripslashes()` workaround and start from the front page with fresh search terms for testing.

Comment: i used it but it won't show the 2nd page of search result for the keyword just can't get enough

Comment: it says No results found for just can\\

Comment: You likely forgot to replace one instance of `$search` with the new `$html_search`. Maybe you could repost your updated code that you  have now for a closer look. -- But btw, if you think my answer at least solved your problem partially, you could click the ✔ check mark left to the answer (gives me points for attempting to be helpful).

Comment: Thank you i forgot to add // prepare for later output:

Comment: Okay cool. These kind of problems are often hard to find. That's why many people use "templating engines" for that. (But they don't simplify things overall, and I would not yet advise it in your case.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running PHP version less than 5.3.0, the slash might be added by the [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) which you can turn off in the .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are important in PHP and MySQL.

A single quote is a delimeter for a string in PHP, for example:

```
$str = 'my string';
```

If you want to include a literal quote inside a string you must tell PHP that the quote is *not* the end of the string. It is *escaped* with the backslash, for example:

```
$str = 'my string with a quote \' inside it';
```

See [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more on this.

MySQL operates in a similar way. An example query might be:

```
$username = 'andyb';
$quert = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username'";
```

The single quote delimits the string parameter. If the `$username` included a single quote, this would cause the query to end prematurely. Correctly escaping parameters is an important concept to be familiar with as it is one attack vector for breaking into a database - see [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for more information.

One way to handle this escaping is with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).